# MySQL - A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-partitioning

I have the following table setup (column names simplified for the example):

```
CREATE TABLE data_2016
( `a` INTEGER , 
  `b` INTEGER,
  `c` VARCHAR(255),
  `d` BIGINT,
  `e` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `f` INTEGER ,
  `g` BIGINT ,
  `h` BIGINT ,
  `i` SERIAL,
PRIMARY KEY (`d`,`i`),
UNIQUE KEY(`b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`,`g`,`h`,`i`),
INDEX `idx1` (`b`,`c`)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (`d`) (
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (...)
...
PARTITION px VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
)
```

But I am getting the exception `A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`

I read through the documentation, and from what I can tell, I **do** have the correct setup.  The partitioned column `d` is included in both the `PRIMARY KEY` and the `UNIQUE KEY` definition.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think the unique index in this case refers to the primary key, not the unique key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but the partitioned column is in both

Comment: . . the `i` column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what about the `i` column?  I'm not partitioning on it.  Is it saying I need to include it in the partition?

Comment: What do you hope to gain by `PARTITIONing`?  It rarely provides any performance benefit.  (I can't guess at the answer because of the obfuscation.)

Comment: @RickJames we have several billion rows of data.  We are partitioning by day, this got our queries down to ~33ms when hitting the keys.  Obfuscation doesn't change the problem...if you run the above create table statement the error is produced.  I'm just trying to understand why the error is appearing even though I have the partitioned column being used in both the PK and Unique Key

Comment: I get `ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes` -- What version are you using?  What is your default engine?  Default charset?

Comment: _Usually_ it is best to put the partition key at the end of indexes.  Having it at the beginning of the `PRIMARY KEY` makes partitioning essentially useless (compared to non-partitioning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `SERIAL` to `INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT` (or whatever is equivalent).  The [*manual*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html) says:

> SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE.

Which means that there is an implicit

```
UNIQUE(i)
```

Which does not include `d`, the partition key.

`CHARACTER SET latin1` is needed to avoid another error about index length.  (8 columns is usually "too long" for an index.)

(And see my comments.)

Comment: Yes, this was it! Thank you!